# convert array to array of object Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, object, foreach

my api receive single array of object from client side like following:

```
[  
         {
         "datetime": "2022-07-19 12:04:03",
         "receiptNumber" : "4010",
         "isRefund": 0,
         "amount" : 1025
          },
]
```

and whem try to validate request at api side checked success and process to database success my issue happen when try to sent multi object inside array like following :

```
[  
         {
         "datetime": "2022-07-19 12:04:03",
         "receiptNumber" : "4010",
         "isRefund": 0,
         "amount" : 1025
          },

         {
         "datetime": "2022-07-19 12:04:03",
         "receiptNumber" : "4009",
         "isRefund": 0,
         "amount" : 1025
          }


]
```

when i am try to validate first object inside array using foreach like following :

```
      $array = $request->all();




      foreach($array as $sdsa){
      


        $this->validate($sdsa, [
          'datetime' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s',
          'amount' => 'required|numeric',
          'isRefund' => 'required|integer|between:0,1',
          'receiptNumber' => 'required|string',
      ]);

}
```

in this case api return error :

```
"message": "Argument 1 passed to App\\Http\\Controllers\\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, array given,
```

so that i am asking how can convert this format:

```
array:4 [
  "datetime" => "2022-07-19 12:04:03"
  "receiptNumber" => "4010"
  "isRefund" => 0
  "amount" => 1025
]
```

to

```
{
array:4 [
  "datetime" => "2022-07-19 12:04:03"
  "receiptNumber" => "4010"
  "isRefund" => 0
  "amount" => 1025
]
}
```

Comment: that `validate` method you are calling takes an `Illuminate\Http\Request` object, a specific object, as that method is for validating the incoming request not an array of data ... if you want to arbitrarily validate data you need to check the docs for "Manually Creating Validators"

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'json_encode()'.

Example;

```
$myArray = array("datetime" => "2022-07-19 12:04:03", "receiptNumber" => "4010", "isRefund" => 0, "amount" => 1025);
```

Output;

```
[ 
  "datetime" => "2022-07-19 12:04:03",
  "receiptNumber" => "4010",
  "isRefund" => 0,
  "amount" => 1025,
]
```

Than if you use json_encode like this;

```
$myArray = json_encode($myArray);
```

Output;

```
{
[ 
  "datetime" => "2022-07-19 12:04:03",
  "receiptNumber" => "4010",
  "isRefund" => 0,
  "amount" => 1025,
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
Validator::make($sdsa, [
      'datetime' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s',
      'amount' => 'required|numeric',
      'isRefund' => 'required|integer|between:0,1',
      'receiptNumber' => 'required|string',
  ])->validate()
```